# Switching between TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT AND TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY , and capturing the touch events not working properly

Tags: android, layout, parameters

I made a View in service which runs always on top of every application in android.

Initially, the behaviour of service is TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT .

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layparams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
 PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
 layparams .gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL| Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
 wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
 wm.addView(serviceView, layparams );
```

I am changing the behaviour of service at run time means switching between TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT AND TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY on touch. Switch take place when I touch outside the view parameters and when touch inside the view  parameters.

```
layparams .type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
Using updateViewLayout(serviceView, layparams )
```

**PROBLEM:** Is when I touch outside of view , the first touch just activate TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY and after then outside app works fine. When TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY  is working , after that when you touch within the view it will trigger the action of object behind the view not the action of the view. But when u once touch the view TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT will be applied and now the View will behave normally .

**Current Implementation** : I have to touch twice to work that particular thing when switch take place between layout parameters.

Answer (score 5):

use this one...  works perfectly on ICS and above

```
params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;//This one is necessary.
params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
params.x = 0;
params.y = -params.height;
windowManager.addView(tile, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by calling `updateViewLayout()` on instance of `WindowManager` class.

```
 wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

 // create new layout params
 WindowManager.LayoutParams newlayparams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
      PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

 //update new layout
 wm.updateViewLayout(serviceView, newlayparams);
```

Hope it help!